# Can't Configure Bash-Shell to Run OpenFOAM (working enviroment)

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've Been trying to download and install OpenFOAM-v1806 for windows 10 using Ubuntu.
I am currently using this guide to help me https://www.openfoam.com/download/install-windows-10.php and am stuck at the Configure the Bash-shell to run OpenFOAM step.

Everytime I open Ubuntu I get this message:

```
-bash /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory
-bash /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory
-bash /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory
```

I assume I have messed up and typed in `echo "source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc` 3 times where it only tells you to do that step once.

following that line I type in `source $HOME/.bashrc` but I just get the same output as when I open Ubuntu as the three repetitive lines of code above.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I assume I made 3 working environments and would like to remove them all, how would I go about this? also why am I getting the no such file or directory error when I have followed the steps on the website link?

If you can help me that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Regardless of how many times you added the line, if `/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc` is not found then it suggests the procedure failed at an earlier step (such as un-`tar`ing the archiive)

Comment: Thanks for the response! where would you recommend I go from here?

Comment: Check for error messages from the previous steps